# js-файлы в качестве шаблонов

Tags: python, django

У меня есть небольшой js-скрипт, который я хотел бы вынести в отдельный js-файл:

```
function user_click(sender, e){

    var addressee = sender.id.substring(3);

    if(sender == e.target){

        var base_url = "{% url 'user' 0 %}";

        base_url = base_url.replace('0', addressee);

        document.location.href = base_url;

    }
    else{

        var data = 'id=' + addressee;   

        POST_AJAX(data, '{% url 'to_man' %}');

    }
}
```

Вся беда в том, что если я выношу его в отдельный файл в директорию static, как рекомендует django, то перестает работать магия шаблонов: в частности тег url. Может быть, кто знает какие-нибудь расширения для джанго, умеющие рендерить js-файлы из папки static?

Comment: Посмотрите на этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/37352754/5201699 идея заключается в том, чтобы в джанго шаблоне объявить переменные, с нужными значениями, которые потом будут использоваться вашим скриптом.

Comment: Если ваша функция вызывается по какому-то событию из джанго шаблона, то возможно при вызове функции можно передать ей аргументы. например `onclick="user_click({% url 'user' 0 %})"`